# VB 2008 convert string "08:30:00" to datetime "08:30:00"

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm working in Visual Studio 2008.

I have a string input in the format "hh:mm:ss" which I want to convert into a dateTime in the same format.

I have used the Convert.ToDateTime() function which converts it but adds a date to it as well.  Is there a way to convert it without adding the date?

```
scanStartString = "08:00:00"
scanStart = Convert.ToDateTime(scanStartString)

'scanStart = "16/05/2011 08:00:00"
'required "08:00:00"
```

Cheers,
Cap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Try TimeSpan instead:

```
Dim time = TimeSpan.Parse("08:00:00")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use TimeOfDay - it will return TimeSpan

```
 scanStart.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the TimeOfDay method onto your convert line...

```
scanStart = Convert.ToDateTime(scanStartString).TimeOfDay
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Dim TimeOfDay As String = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now)
TimeApp.LabelTime.Text = TimeOfDay
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way to do this

```
Dim mydatetime As DateTime
mydatetime = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text)
MsgBox(Format(mydatetime, "HH:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Before answering questions, please completely read the question: **I have used the Convert.ToDateTime() function which converts it but adds a date to it as well. Is there a way to convert it without adding the date?**